# How to show drop menu and hide others in React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I just want to know the best way to proceed (don´t need the code, just the way to do it). I´m trying to show a dropdown menu when I click on it´s LI element.

```
var Balloon = React.createClass({displayName: "Balloon",
        getInitialState: function() {
            return { shaded: false };
        },         
        handleClick: function(event) {
            this.setState({ shaded: !this.state.shaded });
        },
        render: function() {

            var panel = this.state.shaded ? React.createElement(BalloonPanel, {type: this.props.type, data: this.props.data}) : "";

            return (
                React.createElement("li", {onClick: this.handleClick}, 
                    React.createElement("a", {href: ""}), 
                    React.createElement("div", {hidden: true}), 
                    React.createElement("div", null, 
                        React.createElement("div", {class: "triangle"}, " "), 
                        panel
                    )
                )
            );
        }
    });
```

Here is the complete [code](http://jsfiddle.net/termosfera/er3jf6rw/):

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's an OK way to do it if it serves your needs. "Best" is often subjective when it comes to programming style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming your drop downs are all reliant upon one another, i.e.. when you click one the others close etc... than they should all be built with the same object and ascribe to a click event that passes this to the parent.

```
var ParentComponent = React.createClass({
clicked: function () {
  alert("you clicked me");
},
return: function () {
   render (
       <ReactListChild  onClick={this.props.clicked.bind(this)} />
    )
});
```

Keep in mind you need to use the bind method in order for the children to know which one was clicked (to take the appropriate action)

So summing this up, your parent component should have a state variable saying which one to show and set some sort of variable, possibly give it the name of the element or something.  that way if that element is not listed as shown in state the others will remain closed.

fyi, I did not test this code, it's just a rough idea.  Most likely you will do some sort of for loop to render many of these child elements.  Remember the bind, or you'll get burned.